# Transform an M by N matrix (of rank N) into a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

An $M\times N$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has the following form (in a system of linear equations $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\ast  \\
\ast \\
\ast \\
\ast  \\
\ast  \\
\ast  \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The upper part (6 rows and 6 cols marked with $\ast$) has rank 4, the additional two rows at bottom make the entire matrix be rank 6. I suppose there is a way to "merge" the last two rows into $\mathbf{A}$'s upper part to obtain a square matrix of rank 6. How to proceed?

I used some matrix library to check the rank. It employs QR Decomposition to solve the system. But, how to make a neat square matrix manually as its rank equals its dimension?

Comment: How about $A^TA$?

Comment: do you mean solving $A^T A x =A^T b$ instead?

Comment: Yes. Since rank of $A$ is 6, this means $A^T A$ is invertible.